# KBuild fails while compiling without debugging flag

Tags: linux, kernel, module

I am trying to compile a very simple module, but it fails to create *.ko when i am not adding -g flag. Here is the source code:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

static int simple_test_init(void){
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello Kernel!");
    return 0;
}

static void simple_test_exit(void){
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye Kernel!");
}

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Simple test module");

module_init(simple_test_init);
module_exit(simple_test_exit);
```

And here is GCC/Makefile.

```
KBUILD_CFLAGS := -Werror -fcf-protection=branch

obj-m   += test.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

And finally the output of GCC.

```
make -C /lib/modules/5.19.3-arch1-1/build M=/test modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/lib/modules/5.19.3-arch1-1/build'
  CC [M]  /test/test.o
/test/test.o: warning: objtool: folio_flags+0x29: 'naked' return found in RETHUNK build
/test/test.o: warning: objtool: simple_test_init+0x22: 'naked' return found in RETHUNK build
/test/test.o: warning: objtool: simple_test_exit+0x1e: 'naked' return found in RETHUNK build
/test/test.o: warning: objtool: folio_flags+0x29: missing int3 after ret
/test/test.o: warning: objtool: simple_test_init+0x22: missing int3 after ret
/test/test.o: warning: objtool: simple_test_exit+0x1e: missing int3 after ret
  MODPOST /test/Module.symvers
  CC [M]  /test/test.mod.o
  LD [M]  /test/test.ko
  BTF [M] /test/test.ko
pahole: /test/test.ko: No such file or directory
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modfinal:60: /test/test.ko] Error 1
make[3]: *** Deleting file '/test/test.ko'
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modpost:134: __modpost] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1763: modules] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/lib/modules/5.19.3-arch1-1/build'
make: *** [Makefile:6: all] Error 2
```

Thank you.

Comment: What do you think that **-Werror** flag is supposed to do when getting your six warnings ?

Comment: @MC68020 I suppose it should convert all warning into errors? I just do not understand what is this error with naked returns...